# loop until next cells with content

Tags: excel, vba, loops, is-empty

I am new to the forum. I have started working with VBA only recently. However, i already run into a problem.

Imagine the following table

```
 x       y           z               j

 a   b   a   b   c   a   b   c   d   a   b   c

25  22  20  26  25  24  18  28  27  24  18  30
```

I start at x and i want to use the number of cells between x and y to be used as a rule for processing the numbers in row 3.

In the case of x and y. It takes two steps to reach y. So i work with 25 and 22. the loop restarts with y and it takes 3 steps to reach z, so i work with 20 and 25. loop restarts with z .. 4 steps, so 24 and 24, restart with j.

I am especially struggling with the operation to determine the number of steps and to use the number of steps for the next operation.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you intend to do, and the "answer" kind of depends on what you need to do, but you can iterate this table with several statements:

- [`Do ... Loop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278815%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- [`For...Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251601%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- [`For each... Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251601%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Here is an example implementation using `For Each .. Next`:

```
Sub Test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim firstCl As Range
Dim c As Integer     'Counts the columns
Dim i As Integer     'counts the intervals
Dim cl As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:L3") 'modify as needed
c = 1
For Each cl In rng.Rows(1).Cells '## Iterate each cell in first row
    If rng(1, c).Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox i & " cells since the last non-empty cell", vbInformation
        i = 0
    End If
    i = i + 1
    c = c + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestions David. i would like to apply a formula to the numbers in row three (meaning to 25 and 22 under x/ 2o and 25 under y / 24 and 27 etc.

Comment: Hello David, thank you so much. Your solution works for the first step, meaning i can identify the starting point, but i still struggle to define the end point for applying the formula. In other words, i can identify the value under a, but i do not know how to identify numeric value under a-1 (it would be b in the first example, c in the 2nd, d in the 4th). An example would be, i would like to subtract the first from the last value (22-25; 25-20; 27-24...), Thanks, Steve

Comment: THe first cell in the table (A1) could be defined as `rng.Cells(1,1)`, etc.  You can use the `rng.Cells(_row#_, _col#)` to identify different cells within the table. Otherwise, you will need to explore the `Range` object and its methods (`.Offset` may come in handy, as well as `.Resize`).

Answer (score 0):

Try detecting last and first item of interval using tag "a" in second row: item tagged with "a" is the first one of current interval. Last item of previous interval is that one before the first item of current interval. Last item of last interval is last item of entire row.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DetectFirsAndLast()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim formula As String
    Set rng = Range("A1:L3")
    'Identify first and last item of interval in row 2
    For Each cell In rng.Rows(2).Cells
        'Apply formula to first item
        formula = "=1+2"
        If cell.Value = "a" Then
            rng.Cells(3, cell.Column).formula = formula
        End If
        'Apply formula to last item
        formula = "=2+3"
        If cell.Column <> 1 And cell.Value = "a" Then
            rng.Cells(3, cell.Column - 1).formula = formula
        End If
        If cell.Column = rng.Columns.Count Then
            rng.Cells(3, cell.Column).formula = formula
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: *"a" is the first one of current interval,* (not according to the example... the last instance of "a" comes before the next interval would start based on Row 1...

Comment: Yes, i think your idea is a good one. unfortunately, i picked the values a, b, c, d just for this example. i indeed need to base everything on the first row with empty cells between categories.